How to save products in bulk using API?
I am new bee in API development and need to save bulk products in my Magento using API.
Do I need to create custom API module or is there any default API to save the products in magneto2?
What are the steps I need to follow?

There is also bulk endpoint available in magento to create multiple product in one single request. You can look more at official adobe doc

Standard REST API products endpoint can receive multiple products at a time part of the payload:
{
    "products": [
        {
            "sku": "first-product",
            "name": "First Product",
            // other product attributes...
        },
        {
            "sku": "second-product",
            "name": "Second Product",
            // other product attributes...
        }
    ]
}

see the documentation https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.7-admin/tag/products/#operation/PostV1Products
